# Raspberry pi (3) shell script does not properly work when started by cron

Tags: java, gps, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, wiringpi

I've created a simple shell script which basically just starts an ".jar" file.

this script contains the following

```
now=$(date +"%s")
sudo java -jar /home/pi/Desktop/test.jar > /home/pi/Desktop/output_$now.txt
```

I added the script to the crontask with

```
@reboot sudo bash /home/pi/Desktop/testmygps.sh
```

My application is going to be a "GPS controller" which is used for dropping baits for foxes (immunization against rabies).
My application consists of 3 threads, one for updating the connected LCD Display, one for updating the GPS position and speed and one for dropping the baits.

I use serial communication for the GPS Modul (and then extract the needed data) and the pi4j library (v1.1) to communicate with the GPIOs.

When I start the jar from the terminal everything works as expected (so far I just calculate the distances between the drops and save every drop coordinate, and at the LCD shows the current speed and the calculated delay between the drops).

But when I reboot my pi with 'sudo reboot' my jar starts, then a few 'speed updates' are made and then somehow the connection to the connection to the GPS module gets lost and only the LCD continues to work.

Anyone an idea what could be the cause of my problem?

PS.
This is the GPSController class of my project

```
package baitcontrol.v2;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.pi4j.wiringpi.Serial;

import exceptions.NMEAparseException;
import utils.Parser;
import utils.Utils;

public class GPSController implements Runnable {
private static final Logger LOGGER =  
Logger.getLogger(GPSController.class.getName());

private int serialPort;
private static boolean continueLoop = true;

private static GPSController instance;

private GPGGAEvent lastGPGGAUpdateEvent;
private GPVTGEvent lastGPVTGUpdateEvent;

private GPSController() {
    LOGGER.info("GPSController init");
    this.serialPort = Serial.serialOpen("/dev/serial0", 9600);
    LOGGER.info("GPSController initialised");
    if (this.serialPort == -1) {
        LOGGER.severe("Serial Port Failed");
        System.out.println("Serial Port Failed");
    }
}

public static GPSController getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new GPSController();
    }
    return instance;
}


@Override
public void run() {
    LOGGER.info("GPSController started");
    String nmea = "";
    while (continueLoop) {

        if (Serial.serialDataAvail(serialPort) > 0) {
            byte[] rawData = Serial.serialGetAvailableBytes(serialPort);
            for (byte dataByte : rawData) {
                char character = (char) dataByte;
                if (character == '\n') {
                    LOGGER.fine("new nmealine " +nmea);
                    if(nmea.contains("GPGGA")){
                        LOGGER.fine("new GPGGA line");
                        try {
                            lastGPGGAUpdateEvent = Parser.parseGPGGAToGPSEvent(nmea);   
                        } catch (NMEAparseException e) {
                            LOGGER.warning(e.getMessage());
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            Utils.addToTxt("error_" + Utils.dateToString(Main.startTime), e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    if(nmea.contains("GPVTG")){
                        LOGGER.fine("new GPGGA line");
                        try {
                            lastGPVTGUpdateEvent = Parser.parseGPVTGToGPSEvent(nmea);   
                        } catch (NMEAparseException e) {
                            LOGGER.warning(e.getMessage());
                            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            Utils.addToTxt("error_" + Utils.dateToString(Main.startTime), e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                    nmea = "";
                }else{ 
                    nmea+=Character.toString(character);
                }
            }
        } else {
            LOGGER.finest("data empty");
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.finest(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            Utils.addToTxt("error_" + Utils.dateToString(Main.startTime), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public GPGGAEvent getLastGPGGAUpdateEvent() {
    return lastGPGGAUpdateEvent;
}

public GPVTGEvent getLastGPVTGUpdateEvent() {
    return lastGPVTGUpdateEvent;
}

public boolean positionHasAlreadyBeenUpdated(){
    return lastGPGGAUpdateEvent!=null;
}

public boolean speedHasAlreadyBeenUpdated(){
    return lastGPVTGUpdateEvent!=null;
}
```

}

Comment: problem also occurs when jar is directly started in crontab

Comment: solved the problem by using a USB to Serial adapter.